# Print array without loop in php

Tags: php, arrays

I have a array like this

```
 Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [regno] => 2017/032173
[receiveddate] => 2017-04-11 [diarydate] => 2017-04-11 [actiondate] =>
 2017-04-11 [idproofdetail] => [channel] => N [remarks] =>
[grvcategory] => [name] => cdssfsdf [address] => dfsfsdfsd
[grvdistrict] => [grvstate] => [grvcountry] => [pincode] => [gtype] =>
00 [fromorg] => [fromorgname] => Office
 [fromorgofficer] => Sh. BM [fromorgdesignation] =>
 Under Cell ) )
```

I want to print like

```
echo $result->regno;
echo $result->receiveddate;
```

so on

Comment: you can use $result[0]->regno

Comment: whats wrong with a loop?

Comment: if you get some specific value then it's ok. But if you get all values then loop is appropriate.

Comment: @JagdishChaudhary: yes its working

Comment: @NishaGarg yes but it depends on your  array size , if you have multidimensional array then you have to use key like that array, like [1] and like that or [A]

Comment: @NishaGarg can you please write your arrayin proper manage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
$result[0]->regno 
$result[0]->receiveddate
$result[0]->remarks
```